# Regex only writing first match to output file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an input file with text like the following:

```
1,A:E29, A:H31, A:K32, A:K33, A:D34, A:H35,6,0
1,A:L1, A:K2, A:E3, A:A4, A:E5, A:H7,0
```

I would like to write a regex expression to extract such that the output written to my out file would be:

```
A:E29, A:H31, A:K32, A:K33, A:D34, A:H35
A:L1, A:K2, A:E3, A:A4, A:E5, A:H7
```

I wrote some code attempting to do this with a regex following the python documents. For some reason I get the following output:

```
(Empty line)
A:E29, A:L1,
```

My code is the following:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("\w:\w*\d\d*\W\s*")
f= open("masterfile.txt","a+")
for i, line in enumerate(open('inputfile.txt')):
for match in re.findall(pattern, line):
    print(match)
    f.write(match)
    break
else:
    f.write('\n')
```

Also why is my output not at least:

```
A:E29, 
(Empty line)
A:L1,
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well, you break out of your loop, so...

Comment: FYI, `\d\d*` can be simplified to `\d+`. `+` means "1 or more"

Comment: I was trying to use the break to insert a new line to get the expected output. After removing the break the other expected output returned. How do I add the empty line between as i would like in the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `break` or `else:`. Just call `f.write('\n')` after writing the matches.

In the case where there are no matches, you can check for that and write a blank line.

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("\w:\w*\d+\W\s*")
with open("masterfile.txt","a") as f, open('inputfile.txt') as infile:
    for i, line in enumerate(infile):
        matches = re.findall(pattern, line)
        if len(matches) > 0:
            f.write("".join(matches))
        else:
            f.write("\n")
        f.write('\n')
```

Comment: I don't want an blank line in the incidence no matches are found. i want a blank line between each set of matches. For example, line 1 is: A:E29, A:H31, A:K32, A:K33, A:D34, A:H35 line 2 is: blank line line 3 is: A:L1, A:K2, A:E3, A:A4, A:E5, A:H7

Comment: Why did you put it in `else:` then? That's only run when you don't `break`.

Comment: Do you want two blank lines when there are no matches, one for the empty set of matches, and another for the "between" line?

Comment: I thought the way I had it written it would return all matches on a given line. such as: A:E29, A:H31, A:K32, A:K33, A:D34, A:H35 . Then it would go to else and generate a new line and return the next set of matches.

Comment: I'm just wanting a blank "between" line for each set of matches. In my example, set 1: A:E29, A:H31, A:K32, A:K33, A:D34, A:H35 and set 2 is:A:L1, A:K2, A:E3, A:A4, A:E5, A:H7

Comment: Sounds like you don't really understand what `break` does. It means to end the `for` loop, so it doesn't process the rest of the matches. And it only goes to `else` if the loop ends normally, without breaking.